# Read two list in web method

Tags: c#, webforms

Hello I'm having a little problem.

I'm sending some values to WebMethod and I need two list and both foreach(oneCollection and myCollection) to be read an executed.

For now only the first list (oneCollection) is read but the second is not.
I think I have problem with this line of code(I think this is not correct way to read two lists at once.):

```
public static void GetCollection(List<oneCollection> uoneCollection, List<myCollection> omyCollection)
```

The whole code :

```
public class oneCollection
{

    public String lvl { get; set; }
    public String ddl { get; set; }
}

public class myCollection
{
    public String label { get; set; }
    public String opis { get; set; }

}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void GetCollection(List<oneCollection> uoneCollection, List<myCollection> omyCollection)
{

    DataTable tabela2 = new DataTable();
    tabela2.Columns.Add("BusinessCenterID");
    tabela2.Columns.Add("ObjekatName");

    foreach (oneCollection firstcol in uoneCollection)
    {

        string lvl = firstcol.lvl;
        string ddl = firstcol.ddl;

        tabela2.Rows.Add(lvl, ddl);
    }

    DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
    tabela.Columns.Add("CharacteristicID");
    tabela.Columns.Add("CharacteristicValue");

    foreach (myCollection mycol in omyCollection)
    {
        string label = mycol.label; 
        string opis = mycol.opis;


        tabela.Rows.Add(label, opis);
    }
    return;
}
```

Here is the javascript/jQuery code which calls this method:

```
$(function () {
     $('#myButton').on('click', function () {

         var oneCollection = [];
         oneCollection.push({
             lvl: $('#MainContent_txtProductConstruction').val(),
             ddl: $('#MainContent_ddlBusinessCenter').val(),
         })

         var myCollection = [];

         $('#MainContent_gvKarakteristike tbody').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function (i, e) {
             var row = $(e);
             myCollection.push({


                 label: valuefromType(row.find(row.find('td:eq(1)').children())),
                 opis: valuefromType(row.find(row.find('td:eq(2)').children()))

             });

         });

         console.log(myCollection);
         console.log(oneCollection);


     function valuefromType(control) {
         var type = $(control).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
         switch (type) {
             case "input":
                 return $(control).val();
             case "span":
                 return $(control).text();
             case "select":
                 return $(control).val();
         }
     }

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "FirstPage.aspx/GetCollection",

         data: JSON.stringify({ 'uoneCollection': oneCollection, 'omyCollection': myCollection}),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",

         success: function (response) {
             alert("Saved successfully.");
             console.log(response);
         },
         error: function (response) {
             console.log(response);
         }
     });
     //location.reload();
 });
```

Comment: We need to see how the method is being called. Also, `GetCollection` sounds like it should return something.

Comment: This can't be the real code because you only fill 2 local variables. For the rest it looks OK so you will have to debug. Most likely the 2nd list is empty.

Comment: i think second collection is null so could you please share your code from where you are calling this GetCollection method.

Comment: Well, you don´t do anything with `tabela` and `tabela2` after you filled the data. So when you leave the method the tables are both garbage-collected.

Comment: Here the code.
https://jsfiddle.net/L8vj2gka/2/
I must take the values of first two fileds and the columns of the table:

Ajax(200) look's ok:


`omyCollection {…}
0 {…}
label 1
opis rr
1 {…}
label 2
opis r
2 {…}
label 3
opis rr
3 {…}
label 5
opis 1
4 {…}
label 9
opis r
5 {…}
label 15
opis rr
uoneCollection {…}
0 {…}
ddl 2
lvl 444`

Comment: @freej17: always add **relevant** code in the question. Done for you

Comment: Tnx I will do it next ime :)

Comment: Found the solution those tables where the problem thx @AnkitSahrawat